# android canvas drawText

Tags: android, canvas

drawText draws a text from the providing point. But I need different behaviour.
Let's call the point(x,y) as p.
How drawText works:
pMYTEXT
What I need: 
MYTpEXT
So I want to draw text exactly centered with this point. Is this possible?

I think to do it I should measure text and offset the point. But how can I measure it? It has not drawn yet.

Comment: centered related to......??

Comment: @greywolf82 related to providing point (p in my example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  Use the Paint function measureText to get the width of the string you want to the left of point p.  Subtract that length from the x position of p, and draw it there.

Answer (score 0):

Set the paint alignment to center.

```
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER)
```

You can also use LEFT and RIGHT.